# google map custom pointer not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i have put the google map java script code in my site and it does not working.Here is the code

```
function map_initialize() {

        var latlng = [
        __lats_and_langs__
    ];
        if (google.maps.BrowserIsCompatible()) {
                            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=15|FF0000|000000",
                            new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                            new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                            new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
            map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById('salon_map'));
            map.addControl(new google.maps.LargeMapControl3D());
            map.addControl(new google.maps.MenuMapTypeControl());
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0), 0);
                            for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: latlng[i],
                                map: map,
                                icon: image,
                                title: location[0],
                                zIndex: location[3]
                                });

                                //var marker = new google.maps.Marker(latlng[i]);
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            }
            var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i = 0; i < latlng.length; i++) {
                latlngbounds.extend(latlng[i]);
            }
            map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(latlngbounds));
                            map.setZoom(12);
            // put markers and custom icon ??
            __marker_list__
        }
    }
//  google.maps.Event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize);
    google.maps.Event.addDomListener(window, 'unload', google.maps.Unload);
```

Url is : http://myshopsalon.com/find-a-shop-salon

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @alkis i need the custom pointer(number) in the google map.but it is not showing.

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code that you need to resolve. Check the console.log.

Answer (score 1):

The markers are there(you may have noticed the single marker in the top-left corner of the map, it's not 1 marker, all these markers are placed at this location)

Reason: you are using the Maps-Library V2, but you create the Markers with the arguments expected in V3.

In V2 the 1st expected argument is the LatLng, nothing else.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(latlng[i],{/*markerOptions*/});
```

(I've ommitted the options, because you've done the same mistake with the icon )

To clarify: When you use V2, you must use the methods as described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference